# Table not working: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, mysql-workbench

> Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint

( Previous problem was the 1217 error. )
I fixed it to the point of semi-working by adding 'set foreign_key_checks' around the drop tables, only problem is that I get this error at the Orders create table. (CREATE TABLE orders) I looked at the foreign keys in the Orders table, but I'm failing to find anything wrong. I checked all foreign keys and t hey all align properly.

```html
set foreign_key_checks = 0;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS product;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS manufacturer;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dc_location;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS customer;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS details;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS shipping;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS orders;

set foreign_key_checks = 1;

CREATE TABLE manufacturer
(

manufacturer_key            INT             NOT NULL,

manufacturer_name           VARCHAR(20),

manufacturer_address        VARCHAR(20),

manufacturer_city           VARCHAR(10),

manufacturer_state          VARCHAR(10),

manufacturer_postalcode     INT             NOT NULL,

manufacturer_country        VARCHAR(10),

manufacturer_main_phone     INT             NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT manufacturer_pk
    PRIMARY KEY (manufacturer_key)

);

CREATE TABLE dc_location
(

dc_location_key             INT             NOT NULL,

dc_location_name            VARCHAR(15),

dc_location_address         VARCHAR(20),

dc_location_city            VARCHAR(20),

dc_location_state           VARCHAR(10),

dc_location_postalcode      VARCHAR(10),

dc_location_country         INT             NOT NULL,

dc_location_country2         VARCHAR(10),

dc_location_main_phone      INT             NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT dc_pk
    PRIMARY KEY (dc_location_key)

);

CREATE TABLE customer
(

customer_key            INT             NOT NULL,

customer_name           VARCHAR(15),

customer_email          VARCHAR(20),

customer_address        VARCHAR(20),

customer_city           VARCHAR(10),

customer_state          VARCHAR(10),

customer_postalcode     INT              NULL,

customer_country        VARCHAR(10),

customer_main_phone     INT              NULL,

CONSTRAINT customer_pk
    PRIMARY KEY (customer_key)

);


CREATE TABLE product
(

product_key         INT         NOT NULL,

product_name        VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,

product_desc_short  VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,

manufacturer_key    INT         NOT NULL,

dc_location_key     INT         NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT product_pk
    PRIMARY KEY (product_key),

CONSTRAINT product_fk_manufacturer
    FOREIGN KEY (manufacturer_key) REFERENCES manufacturer (manufacturer_key),

CONSTRAINT product_fk_dc_location
    FOREIGN KEY (dc_location_key) REFERENCES dc_location (dc_location_key)

);

CREATE TABLE details
(

order_key               INT             NOT NULL,

product_key             INT             NOT NULL,

product_name            VARCHAR(15)     NOT NULL,

product_desc_short      VARCHAR(15)     NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT details_pk
    PRIMARY KEY (order_key),

CONSTRAINT details_fk_product
    FOREIGN KEY (product_key) REFERENCES product (product_key)

);

CREATE TABLE orders
(

customer_key    INT     NOT NULL,

order_key       INT     NOT NULL,

order_date      DATE    NOT NULL,

shipping_key    INT     NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT orders_pk
    PRIMARY KEY (customer_key),

CONSTRAINT orders_fk_customer
    FOREIGN KEY (customer_key) REFERENCES customer (customer_key),

CONSTRAINT orders_fk_details
    FOREIGN KEY (order_key) REFERENCES details (order_key)

);

CREATE TABLE shipping
(

shipping_key  INT   NOT NULL,

shipping_date  DATE  NOT NULL,

delivery_date  DATE  NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT shipping_pk
 PRIMARY KEY (shipping_key),
    
CONSTRAINT shipping_fk_shipping
 FOREIGN KEY (shipping_key) REFERENCES orders (shipping_key)
    
);

INSERT INTO customer(customer_email) VALUES

('Bandshirt.com'),

('MetallycaBand.com'),

('FeMaidenRocks.com'),

('MetadethMetal.com'),

('Amazoon.com');

INSERT INTO product VALUES

(1, 'Style1', 'Metallyca', 'Short Sleeve', 'XS/S/M/L/XL/XXL'),

(2, 'Style2', 'Metallyca', 'Short Sleeve', 'XS/S/M/L/XL/XXL'),

(3, 'Style1', 'Metallyca', 'Long Sleeve', 'XS/S/M/L/XL/XXL'),

(4, 'Style2', 'Metallyca', 'Long Sleeve', 'XS/S/M/L/XL/XXL'),

(5, 'Style1', 'Fe Maiden', 'Short Sleeve', 'XS/S/M/L/XL/XXL'),

(6, 'Style2', 'Fe Maiden', 'Short Sleeve', 'XS/S/M/L/XL/XXL'),

(7, 'Style1', 'Fe Maiden', 'Long Sleeve', 'XS/S/M/L/XL/XXL'),

(8, 'Style2', 'Fe Maiden', 'Long Sleeve', 'XS/S/M/L/XL/XXL'),

(9, 'Style1', 'Metadeth', 'Short Sleeve', 'XS/S/M/L/XL/XXL'),

(10, 'Style2', 'Metadeth', 'Short Sleeve', 'XS/S/M/L/XL/XXL'),

(11, 'Style1', 'Metadeth', 'Long Sleeve', 'XS/S/M/L/XL/XXL'),

(12, 'Style2', 'Metadeth', 'Long Sleeve', 'XS/S/M/L/XL/XXL');
```

Comment: Please add a tag for the **concrete** RBDMS you're using ....

Comment: _"I keep getting the same error, the 1215, while giving me a warning that courseproject.product, courseproject.manufacturer, etcetc"_ Please quote all the actual errors in full, not just this vague paraphrase of them.

Comment: Added the error code per request, and maybe, I'll try that out, Aaron.

Comment: I corrected some errors but even insert into is wrong. [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=053805599278d58a18872e089f43a635). For example: wrong order of tables, wrong columns, twice the same column names, self-referencing FK, and so on

Comment: Its the ordering of the create tables with the FK's in - you're referencing manufacturer and dc_location before they are created.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Thanks Lad2025 and Matt.

Comment: Not relevant to the question, but integer postal codes are going to cause you some pain. Even the fairly simple US 5 digit ZIPs include codes that start with a leading zero, which will get dropped. Get outside the US, and you're into alpha-numeric codes, codes with dashes, what have you.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: There we go, proper tags added, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

> First execute the tables which doesn't have foreign key references.
>   Post that, execute the remaining tables.

Comment: It worked for a moment, but now I'm getting "Error Code: 1217. Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails".

Comment: Which statement you are trying to execute?

Comment: I'm executing the whole code; I checked all the foreign keys, but I can't seem to find the problem. I reorganized the tables so nothing is called upon before it was created and double checked the foreign keys to make sure they are calling upon the right thing, which they are.